# Mysql Query question

Tags: sql, mysql

I'm trying to work out the following query:

```
             SELECT did_numbers.did_dialstring,
          netareas.netarea_name,
          did_numbers.did_size,              
          CASE WHEN (reseller_id < 1) IS NULL THEN 'F'
          ELSE 'T'
          END as reseller,
          COUNT(*) AS aantal
         FROM did_numbers
         LEFT JOIN reseller_numbers ON (did_numbers.did_number = reseller_numbers.did_number AND reseller_numbers.did_number NOT IN(
         SELECT did_number
    FROM reseller_numbers
    WHERE did_number
    REGEXP  '^31([0-9]{2,3})71([0-9]{4,5})$'
         ))
         LEFT JOIN netareas ON did_numbers.did_dialstring = netareas.netarea_code 
         WHERE did_numbers.did_number NOT IN (
          SELECT did_number
    FROM did_numbers
    WHERE did_number
    REGEXP  '^31([0-9]{2,3})71([0-9]{4,5})$'
         )          
         GROUP BY did_numbers.did_dialstring, did_numbers.did_size, reseller
         ORDER BY did_numbers.did_dialstring, reseller ASC
```

However, it does not seem to work. What happens is the numbers that are found in the subquery's are still counted. What am i doing wrong?

Thanks guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my re-write of your query:

```
   SELECT a.did_dialstring,
          na.netarea_name,
          a.did_size,              
          CASE 
            WHEN reseller_id IS NULL THEN 'F'
            ELSE 'T'
          END as reseller,
          COUNT(*) AS aantal
     FROM DID_NUMBERS a
LEFT JOIN RESELLER_NUMBERS rn ON rn.did_number = a.did_number
                             AND rn.did_number NOT REGEXP '^31([0-9]{2,3})71([0-9]{4,5})$'
LEFT JOIN NETAREAS na ON na.netarea_code = a.did_dialstring
LEFT JOIN DID_NUMBERS dn ON dn.did_number = a.did_number
                        AND dn.did_number NOT REGEXP  '^31([0-9]{2,3})71([0-9]{4,5})$'
    WHERE dn.did_number IS NULL          
 GROUP BY a.did_dialstring, a.did_size, reseller
 ORDER BY a.did_dialstring, reseller ASC
```

If that's still returning the numbers you don't want to see, you're going to have to review the regex you're using to filter the numbers out.

Comment: The rewrite is good, except that the numbers are are taken (Marked as T) are now no longer shown :(.

Comment: @Stephen: `reseller_id` is the only column you didn't provide a table alias, so I don't know which table is not returning a non-NULL `reseller_id` value to determine if your `did_number` filtration is also returning `reseller_id` values that are only NULL.  You need to review your data.